# Use of Taylor Polynomial remainder to show size of error.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, taylor-expansion

I am looking for alternative solutions to the following problem:

Let $f=\sqrt2 \cos(\frac{\pi}{4}+2x)$

1) Find the Taylor polynomial for $f$ of degree 3 at the point 0 and show that: 
$$\lvert f(x)-T_3(x) \vert \le \frac{2\sqrt2}{3}x^4, \ \forall x\in\mathbb{R} $$

2) Use 1) to show $$\lvert \int_{-a}^a f(x)dx -2a+\frac{4}{3}a^5 \lvert  \le \frac{4\sqrt2}{15}a^5$$

I found the error in 1) to be: $\frac{2\sqrt2}{3}x^4$, and I solved 2) by substituting $f(x)$ with $T_3(x)+\frac{2\sqrt2}{3}x^4$ and then solving the integral and the left hand side of the inequality.

I noticed the the right hand side in: $\lvert \int_{-a}^a f(x)dx -2a+\frac{4}{3}a^5 \lvert \le \frac{4\sqrt2}{15}a^5$ is the fifth term of the taylor series for the indefinite integral of $\int f(x)$, maybe this is somehow of use?

I hope, you can help.

Best regards, 
Christoffer.

Comment: **Hint**: The Taylor series of this function is an *alternating series*, so it is easy to compute an upper bound for error after $n$ terms. Can you see how?